# How to change state by passing parameter to setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have dozen of input components. When some of them don't pass validation it gets coresponding propperty "invalidInputName = true" and class "hasError".

When user start typing in those input again, i need to remove "hasError" by changing "invalidInputName" to false. I want to write function clearValidation() witch will be accepting name of parameter and change it to false.

```
class ExchangeForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            paymentAmountValidation: false,
            invalidAccountNum: false,
            invalidPhone: false,
            invalidCheck: false
        }
    }

    // this function toogles input to normal state.
    // I want to pass the name of property which i want to reset 
    // For example: clearValidation('invalidPhone') must work as
    // this.setState({ ...this.state, invalidPhone: false }).
    // But best i've done was { property: propery:false } :(
    // I have to change this.state only with setState()
    clearValidation(property){
        this.setState({ ...this.state, property })
    }

    validation(){
        //it toogles state properties to true if found any error
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
clearValidation(property) {
    this.setState({
        [property]: false
    }
}
```

See the bracket notation section of the [property accessors docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for more information.

Comment: The only good thing of being a dumb junior it's everyday amazing insights about simple things :) Thank you a lot, you have save a lot of time for me!